# Using discord.py, how can I create a bot that constantly updates a file to reflect a point system?

Tags: python, url-rewriting, discord, discord.py

I want to be able to create a bot that gives users a certain amount of points when they execute a command. How can I have a bot constantly update a database with users' ID, name, and the number of points they have? I would also want to be able to subtract from their point total so they can redeem their points for items. Does anyone know any packages or resources I can use to accomplish this? Thank you!

Comment: What's the issue there? I cannot get what's the problem with that. If you don't know how discord.py works you have to read the docs, there's not such a question on your post, if you want a DB you should use one if you don't know how do they work, try to find info about them

Comment: Hi. My issue is that I can't find a suitable resource for what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: sqlite + discord.py